# How to do parallelism in database upserts in pyspark or python

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have the following sample code.  The actual dataframe size is about 1.1 million rows & approximately 100MB size.  The code when run on AWS Glue with 10 / 30 DPUs, takes about 1.15 minutes, which I believe is too much a time.

```
import mysql.connector

df2= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("x103","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ")], ["zip_code","territory_code","territory_name","state"])
upsert_list = df2.collect()

db = mysql.connector.connect(host="xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", user="user1", password="userpasswd", database="ziplist")
for r in upsert_list:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    insertQry = "INSERT INTO TEMP1 (zip_code, territory_code, territory_name, state) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);"
    n = cursor.execute(insertQry, (r.zip_code, r.territory_code, r.territory_name, r.state))
    #print (" CURSOR status :", n)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

FOR UPSERTS:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
insertQry = "INSERT INTO TEMP2 (zip_code, territory_code, territory_name, state, city) SELECT tmp.zip_code, tmp.territory_code, tmp.territory_name, tmp.state, tmp.city from TEMP1 tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE territory_name = tmp.territory_name, state = tmp.state, city = tmp.city;"
n = cursor.execute(insertQry)
print (" CURSOR status :", n)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I found that the issue is caused due to the 2nd line, **df2.collect()** which is taking the entire dataframe to the driver and run it on a single node.  I am trying to do / implement parallelism so that the database operation happens in multiple nodes, is there any way I can do this.

How to implement parallelism for RDS upserts, please share some sample code or pseudo code.

Thanks

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, and please note that I am in a position where I cannot use a JDBC connections, since I have to do INSERT INTO TABLE .....ON DUPLICATE KEY as well.  That is the reason I have used mysql.connector for the glue job.  Please suggest how I can minimize the processing time from 1.15 minutes, to say about 10 - 15 minutes.

Comment: JDBC connections provides for append, overwrite, ignore, error, and I have a requirement to INSERT or UPDATE depending on primary key. The link that was referred for DUPLICATE doesn't discuss much about parrellelism, but about read/write using JDBC.  Thx